# java mouse location

Tags: java, mouse

is there a way of getting just the x co-ordinate or y co-ordinate form

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

??? This is pretty easy:

```
Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
double x = point.getX();
double y = point.getY();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x
```

or

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y
```

Answer (score 1):

found it its ether

```
.getY() or .getX()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class mice {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    while(true){
        //Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("("+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x+", "+MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y+")");
    }
}
```

}